# Typo3 extbase validating custom or manual objects

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase

I have created extbase extension, there for some reason I need to create object manually in create action.

My create action looks like this,

```
/**
* action create
*
* @return void
*/
public function createAction() {
$newObj = new \TYPO3\Myext\Domain\Model\Modelname();
$newObj->setMyval('value');
$this->myrepository->add($newObj);
}
```

Here the problem is its not validating for require field, captcha etc even if I mention @validate NotEmpty in model.
So how to make the validation of manually created object ?
It should throw error to form like out-of-the-box features.
Thank you.

Comment: You must NOT use ``new`` in extbase. Please always use the object manager. Also your object should be handed over by the view. AFAIK the validation is not used if you add it manually to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box validation is only triggered on constructing model objects from GET/POST parameters according to your controller actions signature.

Comment: Here I am adding post paremeters to setFunctions for each fields. Is there any specific code to add before add() ?

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
   /**
    * action create
    * @param \TYPO3\Myext\Domain\Model\Modelname $newObject
    * @return void
    */
    public function createAction(\TYPO3\Myext\Domain\Model\Modelname $newObject) {
        $this->myrepository->add($newObj);
    }
```

Take a look at the [extension_builder](http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-extension_builder), create a model and let the new/create action be generated for you. That will give you a good example on the create action as well as on the new action where the form is being rendered.